# How change VPN pop up dialog permissions?

Tags: android

How change VPN pop up dialog permissions?

I start vpn pop up dialog permission like this:

```java
Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(this);

if (intent != null) {
    VpnStatus.updateStateString("USER_VPN_PERMISSION", "",
         R.string.state_user_vpn_permission,
         VpnStatus.ConnectionStatus.LEVEL_WAITING_FOR_USER_INPUT);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, START_VPN_PROFILE);
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Nice, but how I can change text. I want to set my custom text.

Is it possible?

And second question:

Is it possible to show message always on English. Even I change language on device?

Comment: Hopefully, that is not possible. Otherwise, malware authors will change the text to something that hides that the user is authorizing a VPN and that the VPN can spy on all Internet traffic.

Comment: @CommonsWare But is it possible to show message always on English. Even I change language on device?

Comment: "But is it possible to show message always on English" -- I hope not. It should be in a language that the user understands, which presumably is one of the languages that the user has selected in the Settings app. "Even I change language on device?" -- you cannot change the languages that the user has selected in the Settings app. At most, you can affect the language used in your process, but that will not have an effect on a system dialog like this one.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to show on English when user select Arabic language.

Comment: Why would that be in the user's best interests?

Comment: @CommonsWare because I have not Arabic translates. So as result I show all messages on English (default language)

Comment: You are welcome to show messages **in your app** in English, if you wish. However, the VPN dialog **is not part of your app**, so you cannot control its language.